# Exterior walls or floors?

Tags: walls, floor

I am wanting to build my own spacious house. This is on my pretend world where my family members are the first to be on the planet after scientists so there are no building codes just yet. I have looked up "How to build an exterior wall". Some of the pages I looked at say to do the floor first and then attach the wall to the floor. Others say to do the wall and floor at the same time or to build the walls first and then the floor.

So I looked up "How to build a wood floor". The pages I looked at for that say to build the exterior and interior walls first and then attach the floor to the walls.

So which should I do first, the walls or the floors?

Comment: So as annoying as building codes are, one of their goals is to protect people without a sense of their own abilities and limitations from themselves. This is sort of in the category of "if you have to ask, you shouldn't do it without waaaaaaaaaay more learning and hands-on experience doing smaller projects."

Answer (score 2):

Conventional stick framing in North America has you build the floor first, then build a wood wall on that platform. If your pretend world doesn't have lumber mills, then google yurt.

Comment: Really, because all the pages I have seen on building wood floors say "Build the walls first." This makes even more sense considering that you might have multiple types of flooring in your house.

Comment: And the results that I get when I search "How to build a wood floor" are not just for wood flooring but also for building the subfloor with the floor joists and everything else.

Comment: AD is correct for modern framing techniques. Old-style "balloon framing"  framed walls first, if I remember correctly, but that had several disadvantages, not least requiring longer lumber than is easily available now.

Comment: Really no fooling. What I fear you might be getting stuck on is the distinction between a structural floor (joists/subfloor, or concrete slab, or something else), and a finish floor (hardwood/ tile/ vinyl/ cork/ you-name-it). So, to be super clear: floor structure. Wall sitting on floor. Exterior finish on wall to keep weather out. Now you can do interior finish work (floor/wall/etc).